# Jms session.commit() throws exceptoin when I run my application in Jboss server

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ v5.11.1 with managed beans on Jboss EAP v6.3 server so I get exception when i perfrom jms session.commit() or rollback()

```
(ActiveMQ Session Task-1) javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Not a transacted  session
```

But when i run as java application it gives no exception why ?
Could it be because of version mismatch ?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#createSession-boolean-int-).
If your jms resource is controlled by JTA, you can't commit or rollback manually

Comment: I got to know about active JTA , but in my application creation of session is not part of JTA but yes a transaction is created at the time of processing the message after recieving it. So in this case is jms resource/session part of JTA?